# Windows explorer slow, specifically after opening an archive

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-explorer, zip, cpu-usage

I recently noticed my windows explorer drastically slowing down and increasing its CPU usage after having opened a zip, a problem that stays even AFTER having navigated out of the zip. With this I mean that opening folders takes more time (up to a few seconds, instead of basically instant). Curiously enough, the problem is fixed by opening a new instance of the explorer. However, it is quite annoying that I have to do this every time I open an archive.

I have added a screenshot of the performance monitor while browsing around in the epxlorer. The first big spike is when I open a file on my physical drive (which I barely ever use) for the first time. The large spikes in the middle are after opening a zip. The small spikes in the end are after opening a new instance of the explorer.
[Explorer % Processing time (green line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aJ70.png)

I'd love to know what causes this and how it could be fixed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could be a Context issue.   These are difficult to find. Look at Nirsoft (.net) Shell View x64

Comment: It could be the anti-malware software (Derfender or an alternative) is examining all the files in the archive. BTW, do you have the same issue with a third-party archive app, such as 7-Zip? If not, I'd see that as reason to make that app the default for opening ZIP, ISO, CAB and other archives.